# Session dont assumes values data base

Tags: php, html

I have my php code all done and functional but to upgrade to the 7.x version of php, the session crashed. It says that the data entered are wrong but they are in the database. 
already checked all the pages have the session_start() in all pages, just do not understand why not read data from the database.
someone can help me?

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data", "aaa");

$db = mysqli_select_db("dados", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session

$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysqli_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>


    <?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username ou Password são inválidos";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data", "aaa");
// Check connection
//if ($connection->connect_error) {
  //  die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
//} 
//echo "Connected successfully";
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db("dados", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("Location: menu.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username ou Password são inválidosS";
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

`

Comment: `mysqli_query()` needs first parameter as connection then query Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Below you mention that you do not see errors. Do you have the displaying of errors enabled? (do you ever see PHP errors?)

Comment: Rollback your edit. It is hard to understand the problem if you remove the code. The answers or questions may help future users solve their problem fast. Without the code they may not understand the problem or any possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the connection to `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, and in `mysqli_select_db()` you should set the connection first then the db name:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data", "aaa");

$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "dados");
session_start();// Starting Session

$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysqli_query($connection, "select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connection, $ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
    mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}


session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Username ou Password são inválidos";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data", "aaa");
// Check connection
//if ($connection->connect_error) {
  //  die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
//} 
//echo "Connected successfully";
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db("dados", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
        header("Location: menu.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
      } else {
        $error = "Username ou Password são inválidosS";
     }
        mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try it now, and send me a screenshot about the errors you've got. I nee to know what errors you have so I can provide more help.

Comment: I dont have errors, I have users entered in the database and try longin and go to to this part, else {
        $error = "Username ou Password são inválidosS";
     }                                                                                                       Just wanted the session to work and could log Thanks for the help

Comment: send me your teamviewer credentials I will connect live to your PC and fix it. But not now, in 20 minutes.

Comment: its no other solution?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data", "aaa","dados");
```

instead of

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "data", "aaa");

$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "dados");
```

for connection

and query syntax like

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
```